# Installing @Forge/cli is bringing spawn ts-node ENOENT error

Tags: jira, npm-install, jira-rest-api, jira-forge

I followed this tutorial [Getting started](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/getting-started/#install-the-forge-cli) on Jira development.

I’m on a Mac so I went through those steps: [Installing Forge on macOS successfully](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/installing-forge-on-macos/).

When I install forge Globally:
npm install -g @forge/cli

I get this error:

```
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ts-node ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn ts-node',
  path: 'ts-node',
  spawnargs: [
    '/Users/soud/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.6/lib/node_modules/@forge/cli/out/workers/forge-cli-workers.ts',
    '{"name":"@forge/cli","checkForUpdate":true,"environment":"prod"}'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Link to the answered question: https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/installing-forge-cli-is-bringing-spawn-ts-node-enoent-error/52843/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the answer I got from the Forum:

looking at the error and at our postinstall script, it seems like you may have NODE_ENV=development set in your shell environment.

Perhaps you had set it earlier in the same terminal session, or maybe it’s set in your bashrc or bash_profile?

To confirm whether this is the issue, you could unset the NODE_ENV in your terminal session before running npm install -g @forge/cli by running unset NODE_ENV.